# Webpack-serve - reduce logging

Tags: webpack, elm, webpack-serve

I'm trying to use webpack-serve to support an Elm development environment. My problem is that I am getting a huge amount of unneeded logging that pushes the compiler messages quickly off of the screen - see picture.

I have the following in my webpack.config.js with the two lines marked **** designed to reduce noise, but seemingly without any success. What can I do next?

```
    module.exports = merge(common, {
        plugins: [
            // Suggested for hot-loading
            new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
            // Prevents compilation errors causing the hot loader to lose state
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.elm$/,
                    exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'elm-hot-webpack-loader' },
                        {
                            loader: "elm-webpack-loader",
                            options: {
                                // add Elm's debug overlay to output
                                debug: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        serve: {
            logLevel: "silent",   *********
            stats: "errors-only", *********
            inline: true,
            content: [path.join(__dirname, "src/assets")],
        }
    });
}
```

[image: webpack output]

Comment: `stats` should do it. Try moving it to the top level object, out of `serve`.

Comment: :-( thanks for the idea, but it did not change anything